# Do we need to call fs.close() explicitly while working with HDFS using java API?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs

Typical start of working with HDFS using `org.apache.hadoop.fs` classes on scala is

```
val conf = new Configuration()
fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
```

Do we need to call something like
`IOUtils.closeStream(fs)` or `fs.close()` at the end?

I've found the single answer relating to this topic
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/Mn9KLbtmh7M

> In all my experience you let FileSystem instances close themselves.

I am not sure I can rely on it.

Comment: This seems to cover your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057881/hadoop-filesystem-closed-exception-when-doing-bufferedreader-close

Answer (score 0):

You can always use try with resources:

```
try (fs = FileSystem.get(conf)) {
  < your code>
}
```

Since FileSystem is closeable it will be closed at the end of the "try" scope